# Using SiftGPU in Android (about ndk, cmake and SSE)

Tags: android, cmake, android-ndk, sse

Recently I am trying to use SiftGPU in Android. I am using the Linux. So, first I download a ndk and use the following code to get a standalone toolchain:

```
sudo sh ./build/tools/make-standalone-toolchain.sh --verbose --platform=android-15 --install-dir=/home/YourUserName/Downloads/my-tool --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.9
```

Then, I add the some codes to the CmakeLists.txt so it becomes:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)

PROJECT(SIFTGPU C CXX)

set(NDK_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN /home/YourUserName/Downloads/my-tool/)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Android)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 15)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${NDK_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN}/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${NDK_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN}/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI armeabi-v7a)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${NDK_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN})
add_definitions("--sysroot=${NDK_STANDALONE_TOOLCHAIN}/sysroot")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-write-strings -Wno-unused-result -Wno-deprecated -fPIC")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wno-write-strings -Wno-unused-result -Wno-deprecated -fPIC")

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(src)
```

After that, I simply go to the directory of SiftGPU, create a new folder, enter it, and run:

```
cmake ..
```

Until now, everything seems ok. However, after I run the following command, well, unfortunately, it doesn't work:

```
make
```

And here is the error:

```
[  9%] Building CXX object src/SiftGPU/CMakeFiles/siftgpu.dir/FrameBufferObject.cpp.o
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: unrecognized argument in option '-march=core2'
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: note: valid arguments to '-march=' are: armv2 armv2a armv3 armv3m armv4 armv4t armv5 armv5e armv5t armv5te armv6 armv6-m armv6j armv6k armv6s-m armv6t2 armv6z armv6zk armv7 armv7-a armv7-m armv7-r armv7e-m armv7ve armv8-a armv8-a+crc iwmmxt iwmmxt2 native
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '-mfpmath=sse'
src/SiftGPU/CMakeFiles/siftgpu.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'src/SiftGPU/CMakeFiles/siftgpu.dir/FrameBufferObject.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/SiftGPU/CMakeFiles/siftgpu.dir/FrameBufferObject.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:103: recipe for target 'src/SiftGPU/CMakeFiles/siftgpu.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/SiftGPU/CMakeFiles/siftgpu.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I tried to google it but I didn't get any useful result. It seems that the ndk complier is not compatible with SSE. Does anyone have any idea about this question?

Comment: ARM doesn't have SSE.  That's an x86 ISA extension.  ARM has VFP (scalar floating point), NEON (SIMD), or on some CPUs, no floating point hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like their CMake files weren't meant to be cross-compiled.

> arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error: unrecognized argument in option '-march=core2'

core2 is only valid for x86.

You'll need to take a look through SiftGPU's CMakeLists.txt to see if there are options for cross-compiling, and if not, just remove that flag.